# A question on sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X\neq\emptyset$, $A=\{{B\in{R} : |B|< \infty \text{ or } |B^{c}|<\infty}\}$.
Find an example in which :

1. $(X,A)$ is a sigma-algebra space.($A$ is a sigma-algebra on $X$).
2. $(X,A)$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra space.
3. Find a condition on $X$ that ensure satisfy: $(X,A)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra space.

I took:

1. $X={1,2,\ldots\,n}$
2. $X=R$

Is that okay?

Can you suggest a way to solve 3.

Thanks!

Comment: $A$ is **defined** to be the collection of all subsets of $X$ that are finite or have finite complement. You don't get to decide who $A$ is once you decide who $X$ is. If $X=\{1,2,3\}$, then $A$ must be **all** subsets of $X$, because every subset of $X$ is finite. None of your examples are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A$ is defined as $A=\{{B\in{R} : |B|< \infty \text{ or } |B^{c}|<\infty}\}$. So you can not choose $A$. $A$ is the collection of all subset of $X$ that are finite or whose complement is finite. You can only choose $X$.

1. If $X$ is finite, the $A$ is the collection of all subset of $X$. So $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.
2. If $X$ is not finite, then there is $E\subseteq X$ such that $E$ is infinite **countable** set and $E^c$ is infinite. Clearly $E\notin A$. But, for all $p\in E$, $\{p\}\in A$ and
   $$ E= \bigcup_{p\in E} \{p\} $$
   So $A$ is not a  $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.
3. From the above it is clear that  $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ if and only if $X$ is a finite set.